# add data in loop with db.commit() sqlalchemy PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, commit

I need help with Python code

```
copy_groups = Group()
groups = Group.query.filter(Group.project_id == curent_project_id)
for group in groups:
    copy_groups.project_id = curent_project.id
    copy_groups.name = group.name
    db.session.add(copy_groups)
db.session.commit()
```

When I used this code it was added only last `group`, but I need add all `group` in `groups`.

When I used

```
copy_groups = Group()
groups = Group.query.filter(Group.project_id == curent_project_id)
for group in groups:
    copy_groups.project_id = curent_project.id
    copy_groups.name = group.name
    db.session.add(copy_groups)
    db.session.commit()
```

I had error.

But I need add all `group` in `groups`

Please help me  with this problem. Thank you.

Comment: create `copy_groups = Group()` inside `for` loop

Comment: @furas 
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1062, "Duplicate entry 'owners-60' for key 'group_project_id_index'") [SQL: 'INSERT INTO `group` (project_id, active, name, manager_id) VALUES (%(project_id)s, %(active)s, %(name)s, %(manager_id)s)'] [parameters: {'manager_id': None, 'project_id': 60, 'name': 'owners', 'active': 1}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code is meant to copy the project, and the code that I never published, was a line

```
copy_project.create_default_groups (current_user, tenant = tenant)
```

due to which the copying was carried out duplication, which is why all Feil. removing this line, everything works correctly.

Comment: it is the final answer